# Big O-notation for some exponential

Tags: analysis

Suppose $\mu>0$ and $\lambda <0$ with $\lvert\lambda\rvert >\mu$.

Is it true that
$$
x e^{2\lambda x}=O(e^{-2\mu x}), \textrm{as }x\to\infty?
$$

I am really not sure.

I think, I have to show that there exists some $\varepsilon >0$ and some $X$ such that
$$
xe^{2\lambda x}\leq \varepsilon e^{-2\mu x}\textrm{ for all }x>X.
$$

Comment: Can you show $\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{-x}=0$?

Comment: Yes, by L'Hospital

Comment: Can you show $\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{\alpha x}=0$ where $\alpha=2(\lambda+\mu)<0$?

Comment: Yes, also by L'Hospital

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean.. For large x, I get that $xe^{2\lambda x}e^{2\mu x}\leqslant\varepsilon$. So, in fact, I have a stronger statement, namely small-oh, i.e. $xe^{2\lambda x}=o(e^{-2\mu x})$, as $x\to\infty$. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving everything to the other side we have

$$xe^{2(\lambda+\mu)x}\le\varepsilon$$

However, we know by taking the limit as $x\to\infty$, the LHS tends to $0$, and hence this holds for arbitrarily small $\varepsilon>0$. This not only gives the desired result, but the stronger $xe^{2\lambda}\in o(e^{-2\mu x})$ as $x\to\infty$.